# OAuth exchange giving invalid_grant and Bad request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm running into some weird behavior when trying to use OAuth for a local Node.js script. My goal for right now is to obtain a refresh token from the user when they authorize my project.

I'm trying to rely as much as I can on Google's libraries but am still having issues with it.

When I try to run the setup, I correctly get the OAuth page and create an authorization token:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
);
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
];
```

I provide the URL to the user in the console:

```
const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
    access_type: 'offline',

    // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
    scope: scopes
});

console.log(url);
```

Then I open the URL and generate the token. I prompt the user to provide this value:

```
stdio.question('Authorization code', (err, code) => {
    // Use this code to obtain a refresh token
    console.log("CODE", code);
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
        console.log(err, tokens);
    });
});
```

When I get to this point, I run into an error:

```
error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request'
```

And it's not clear where this is going wrong.

If I take the same auth token and use cURL, it actually works as expected, so it's not a configuration error as far as I can tell.

```
curl -s -X POST -d 'code='$CODE'&client_id='$CLIENT_ID'&client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET'&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

{
  "access_token": "ACCESS",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "REFRESH"
}
```

What's even more interesting is that if I run through the flow and get the error, trying to run the cURL command will return an error that indicates the request was accepted to some degree:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Code was already redeemed."
}
```

What is happening in this OAuth library that is causing the invalid grant issue that is not happening with cURL, and what can I do to correct the Node.js code?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an issue of the `stdio` library is that all of the text that you enter ends up being [converted to lowercase](https://github.com/sgmonda/stdio/issues/21) before you get it in the callback. This is what resulted in the `invalid_grant` error.

The better way is to use the built-in `readline` module in Node.js

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Authorization code: ', (code) => {
  // Use this code to obtain a refresh token
  console.log("CODE", code);
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
    console.log(err, tokens);
    rl.close();
  });
});
```